# Criptografia em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, criptografia, facebook

Em meu site uso a API do Facebook, por intermédio do `ACCESS_TOKEN`. Essa 'chave' da acesso à tudo que a aplicação correspondente pode fornecer, ou seja, não é viável deixá-la pública. Em vista disso, gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de 'esconder' essa chave.
Segue abaixo parte do código referente à pergunta:

```
var endereco = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ page_id +"/posts?access_token="+ token +"&limit=15";

      $.getJSON(endereco, function(data) {
          //função
      });
```

Comment: Esconder essa chave de quem? Do próprio usuário? Ou de um terceiro?

Comment: De terceiros e do próprio usuário. Uso o Jekyll e ele tem a opção de hospedar o CMS no GitHub, como o código é aberto nesse repositório, todos terão acesso à minha access_token. :(

Comment: Enquanto escrevia a resposta não percebi que havia editado o comentário... Infelizmente, enviar algo para o usuário e esconder isso dele são dois objetivos conflitantes, não tenho nada a sugerir a respeito. A única forma seria usar criptografia no lado do servidor, mas se você quer que o próprio usuário se comunique com o Facebook (chamando o Graph API via JavaScript no browser) então em algum momento o usuário vai ter que ter acesso a esse token na forma original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credenciais de acesso (senhas, chaves, tokens) não devem nunca ser armazenados no código-fonte (*hardcoded*) mas sim fazer parte de um arquivo de configuração (i.e. dados). Não conheço o Jekyll, mas uma rápida olhada na [documentação](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) sugere o arquivo `_config.yaml` (você que está mais familiarizado deve conhecer o local mais adequado). A razão é simples: ainda que você consiga dar total segurança aos seus fontes, no caso de uma brecha (invasão/quebra/vazamento) você teria que modificar o programa para consertá-la - em vez de mexer em um único arquivo.

Quanto a manter esse token de acesso confidencial, tenho alguns comentários:

- Se você está usando `https`, ele deve estar bem protegido contra interceptação (*man-in-the-middle*). Mesmo na query string. Em geral não é bom usar dados confidenciais na query string (pois eles podem acabar nos logs do servidor), mas se é inevitável pelo menos ela está protegida pelo `https`.
- Se o token de acesso é único por usuário (i.e. cada usuário só pode utilizar mal o seu próprio token) então não há problema, mas se um único token puder afetar a vários usuários você não deve revelá-lo nem a eles. Afinal, um único usuário malicioso pode comprometer a segurança de todos os outros.

  - A alternativa seria ter um script no lado do servidor que faria o meio campo entre o cliente e o Facebook. O token nesse caso não sairia do servidor.
- Tudo isso assume que você confia no provedor de hospedagem onde está o seu código. Se você não confiar nele, há pouco o que fazer a respeito.

Answer (score 3):

Cara realmente é complicado... Porque todo mundo pode ter acesso ao teu arquivo Javascript então mesmo se você "encriptar" terá que tirar a encriptação por meio de alguma função ou algo do tipo para fornecer par o Facebook. Nesse caso a pessoa poderia ir no código fonte da função e fazer o modo reverso para tirar a encriptação.

Resumindo você fará um trabalho que não terá sucesso.

Uma saída e fazer um webservice onde você acessa pelo seu JS e de lá você escolhe o que pode ser acessado.

Comment: Pra esse caso pode ser usada obfuscação do código, o que dificulta bastante as coisas.

Comment: @D.Melo Dificulta como? Não é trivial recuperar o token a partir do código ofuscado?

Comment: O código em si fica inelegível, o que dificulta saber onde nele está o token. De fato, se ele está no javascript não tem forma de esconder. O obfuscamento so serviria pra dificultar as coisas. Se bem que a URL do facebook é facil de encontrar. :p